# sqlcmd Exit Code Handling in for....loop (Jenkinsfile) and handling domain based authentication

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sqlcmd

I have the below command which executes all the sql scripts in a folder.
I am using Jenkins Pipeline to execute the below command.

Problem :
In current scenario I have 4 scripts

Ex: 01.sql, 02.sql, 03.sql, 04.sql

If any script fails in first three and the last one executes successfully , it doesn't raise alert of failure in Jenkins, as the last exit code is Success.

Is there any other way to handle it ? Below is the Pipeline Section.

```
// Execute SQL Scripts
        stage('Execution Scripts Section') {
            steps {
                script
                    {
                    bat """
                    cd src\\sql_scripts"
                    set target_db=${db}
                    for /R %%i in (*) do sqlcmd -S%db% -E -b -i"%%i"
                    """
                    }
            }
        }
```

Additions : 
SQL Server username and password works fine with -E(system user). How to pass a domain based user with password in sqlcmd ? I tried the below command it fails.

```
sqlcmd -S%db%  -U%user% -P'%pass%' -b -i"01.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to separate your multi-line bat command into a series of single-line bat commands.

```
bat """"
    cd src\\sql_scripts
"""
bat """"
    set target_db=${db}
"""
bat """"
    for /R %%i in (*) do sqlcmd -S%db% -E -b -i"%%i"
"""
```

Each one of those will throw an error if the command exits with a non-zero code (which is not necessarily the case for multi-line bat commands)